# Found a note in my desk

Tags: cipher

I found this note in my desk, my office is quite old so I have no idea where it came from, the desk came out of storage so I also have no idea who had it before me.

The paper was folded, on the front was

83 111 117 110 100, 73 116, 79 117 116

Which in ascii is:

S o u n d, I t, O u t

Sound it out

On the inside was:

vuvuaytchayytee deeoheees teeaytchayees esayywhy

Any guesses? I have a couple but I do not want to cloud any first judgement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you "sound out" the things on the inside, it spells:

> vuvu - ?
>  aytch - H
>  ayy - A
>  tee - T
>  dee - D
>  oh - O
>  ee - E
>  es - S
>  tee - T
>  aytch - H
>  aye - I
>  es - S
>  es - S
>  ayy - A
>  why - Y

and this makes:

> "WHAT DOES THIS SAY".

Comment: I guess the intention is that 'vu' is sounded like with a silent v, making it sound like 'yu', making 'vuvu' -> 'double-yu'

Comment: Thanks that was the answer, I was just a little new guy hazing, thanks for help. I had a felling, but I also had a feeling it would lead to a million dollars too.